# Bypass six month passport-validity rule when already in country

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passport-renewals, denial-of-entry, peru

Two of my family just arrived at the Jorge Chavez International Airport in Lima, Peru (from the U.S.) for a vacation (tourism), but one of them has a passport that expires in two months. Peru follows the [six month rule](https://www.us-passport-service-guide.com/foreign-entry-requirement-OP.html#Peru) for passport validity, something we were not aware of until now.

Now immigration (in Peru) is not letting them enter the country. From what I've read online, there's no bypassing the rule, and often people are not allowed to board their flights. What is the best way to handle this situation (hopefully to continue the vacation as planned)?

(If it makes any difference, they first departed from JFK (NYC) to Bogota, Columbia, and then Bogota to Lima.)

Comment: He should contact his consulate in Peru, and let them negotiate with the Peruvian government. Maybe they can issue him an emergency passport?

Comment: How long were they planning to stay in Peru? The US Consulate may be able to help https://pe.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/local-resources-of-u-s-citizens/emergency-assistance/

Comment: @gstorto and Traveller: It was a week-long trip. They contacted the consulate, but they said the consulate wouldn't help. They're planning to return home now.

Comment: Indeed, the consulate probably can't help because they have to get past Peruvian immigration controls before they can get to the consulate to apply for a new passport.

Comment: @phoog If that was the case, is it possible that the other family member goes to apply for a new passport while leaving the other at the airport? (They're  both adults.) I'm not sure exactly what the consulate said, but maybe this is possible.

Comment: @JonathanLam you mean, the one eligible to enter applies for the passport for the one ineligible to enter?  That won't work for many reasons.

Comment: @Moo call me clueless, but that’s what I was thinking. I don't know what the "many reasons" are

Comment: @JonathanLam two main issues I can think of: firstly, an embassy or consulate is unlikely to provide emergency travel documents for someone to a third party unless the situation is extremely special, and secondly, the Peruvian immigration have no obligation to wait.  It's unlikely the embassy or consulate will go out of their way to help a tourist who simply didn't follow well published requirements for entry into the country, as that person is in no danger and will simply be returned to the US.

Comment: @Moo the main reason it won't work is that [To apply for an emergency passport, you must apply in person at the Embassy, Consulate, or Consular Agency...](https://mx.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passport-services/emergency-passport/).

Comment: @phoog as I alluded to in my comment - in very special cases an embassy or consulate would definitely issue documents to a person not present during application, but we are talking about hospitalisation or other serious situations there, not this.

Comment: Strange, the airline should have refused to allow them to fly with passports close to expiration. Timatic has the six-month rule clearly showing for this nationality and destination. Peru can issue the airline quite a large fine for that. If they had been denied boarding at JFK they could possibly have gotten same-day replacement passports and rebooked the trip. But there is very little your family members can do at the airport in Peru except for leave on the next flight out of the country.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I’m not sure why they were allowed to fly in the first place either, but I’m thinking it was most likely because it wasn’t a direct flight, but even then Colombia also follows the six month passport validity rule. If they had been stopped before flying it would have saved some money and strife, agreed.